# Why positive numbers are not stored by 2's compliment?

Tags: c, char

I have heard that negative numbers in the range of `chars` are stored by 2's compliment.
Why this is so with only negative numbers?
Why positive numbers are not stored by 2's compliment?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Did they explain what 2's complement means along with it?

Comment: Positive and negative numbers may be stored in a 2's complement format.

Comment: Because 2's complement is a method for storing numbers in such a way that they behave like *negative* numbers when added to other numbers, which may be positive or negative.

Comment: For the same reason positive numbers are not written with a negative sign.

Comment: Both positive and negative numbers use 2's complement; we represent -5 as the 2's complement of 5 (0101 => ~0101 + 1 => 1011).  But by that same token, we represent 5 as the 2's complement of -5 (1101 => ~1101 + 1 => 0101).  It's just that positive numbers look the same as their unsigned counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

The two’s complement of a number *x* is 2<sup>*n*</sup>-*x*, where *n* is the number of bits being used to store a number.

In a two’s complement *system* of representing integers, positive numbers are stored as their regular (binary encoded) value, and negative numbers are stored as the two’s complements of their magnitudes.

E.g., four four bits:

```
 0 = 0000 (binary)
 1 = 0001
 2 = 0010
 3 = 0011
 4 = 0100
 5 = 0101
 6 = 0110
 7 = 0111

-8 = 16-8 =  8 = 1000
-7 = 16-7 =  9 = 1001
-6 = 16-6 = 10 = 1010
-5 = 16-5 = 11 = 1011
-4 = 16-4 = 12 = 1100
-3 = 16-3 = 13 = 1101
-2 = 16-2 = 14 = 1110
-1 = 16-1 = 15 = 1111
```

Thus, the two’s complement system is a way of splitting an unsigned binary range into two pieces and using half of it (with the initial 0 bit) for non-negative numbers (encoded in simple binary) and the other half (with the initial 1 bit) for negative numbers (encoded with two’s complement).

This system has some nice properties, notably that simple arithmetic is the same for the two’s complement system as it is for unsigned binary. Consider adding 1100 and 0101:

```
  Bits    Plain Binary    Two’s Complement System
  1100    12              -4
+ 0101     5               5
  ----    --              --
  0001     1 (wrapped)     1
```

Comment: why non-negative numbers are encoded in simple binary and negative numbers are encoded in 2's compliment

Comment: @zee: We start with a system for representing non-negative numbers: Plain binary. Then we need to fit negative numbers into the system somehow. Two’s complement does that by changing negative numbers into something that fits into the system well. There is no need to change non-negative numbers because they are already in the system.

Comment: why range of char is from -128 to +127 but not -127 to +128, as 2's compliment of -128 is same as binary of +128

Comment: @zee: Well, it is pretty clear that 00000000 ought to be 0 and 00000001 to 01111111 ought to be 0 to 127, and 10000001 to 11111111 ought to be -127 to -1. That just leaves 10000000. What should it be? It “fits” on the end of either 1 to 127 (because adding 1 to 01111111 produces 10000000) or -1 to -127 (because adding -1 to 10000001 produces 10000000). It turns ought it just fits better to make it negative. That way, all the things that start with a leading 1 bit are negative. It makes a better pattern than having 10000000 be an exception that is positive.